# Programming in c depends on operating system

Tags: c, macos, unix, compiler-errors, compilation

The problem is the next. I have a repository where i work, and two computers where I code. Yesterday I made a program that works on one of this computers, then I made a push in my repository. Today I have download the content of this repository but it doesn't compile.

Its possible that the code depends of my os (one machine have OSX and the other Ubuntu).

Thanks

Ok, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum chess {W, BL, WK, WQ, WP, WR, WH, WB ,BK, BQ, BP, BR, BH, BB};
static const char *chess_string[] = {"O", "X", "WK", "WQ", "WP", "WR", "WH", "WB" ,"BK", "BQ", "BP", "BR", "BH", "BB"};
typedef enum chess chess;

enum chess_letter {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H};
static const char *chess_letter_string[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
typedef enum chess_letter chess_letter;

const int x=8;
const int y=8;

chess table [x][y];

void init_table(int x, int y, chess arr[x][y]){

    int i,j;

    int c=0;


    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(j=0;j<y;j++){
            if(c==1){
                c=0;
                arr[i][j]=BL;
            }else{
                c=1;
                arr[i][j]=W;
            }
        }
        if(c==1){
            c=0;
        }else{
            c=1;
        }
    }
}

void print_table(int x, int y, chess arr[x][y]){

    int i;
    int j;

    printf("  ");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("%s  ",chess_letter_string[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("%d ",i+1);
        for(j=0;j<y;j++){
            printf("%s  ",chess_string[arr[i][j]]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

int main(){

    init_table(x,y,table);
    return 0;
}
```

It works in OSX but it doesn't in Ubuntu. This is the error:

```
chess.c:14:7: error: variably modified ‘table’ at file scope
 chess table [x][y];
       ^
chess.c:14:7: error: variably modified ‘table’ at file scope
```

I use gcc to compile it.

```
gcc chess.c -o chess
```

Comment: If you use OS-specific functions then yes of course the code depends on operating system. Also note that there are basically two variants of Unix left, [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) (of which macOS is a variant) and [SYSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) (of which Linux mostly inherits from). There are small differences between the two variants which might lead to problems. Without more details (and preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: Very probable, but it's impossible to answer a question with so little details. Can you share some code and the error you're getting?

Comment: Even if you don't use OS-specific functions, it may depend on compiler specific **extensions**. Or the support for *standard C* is different between the compilers. It's impossible to answer what you may have done wrong.

Comment: The answer to your question is: __yes__. If you want more détails, you need to provide at least the error messages from the compiler you get.

Comment: 'touch' everything, rebuild everything.

Comment: Saying which compiler and the version  would help too.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a version problem.